# Overloading operator and create new object

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading, move-semantics

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <gtest\gtest.h>
class Money
{
public:
    explicit Money(int value) :value(value) {} ;
    Money(Money&& m) :value(m.returnValue()) {};
    Money(const Money &m) = default;
    Money operator-(const Money &m) ;
    Money operator+(const Money &m);
    Money operator=(Money &&m) { return Money(m.returnValue()); };
    Money &operator=(const Money &m)=default;
    int returnValue() const { return value; };
    ~Money() = default;
private:
    int value;
};
Money Money::operator-(const Money &m)
{
    return Money(value - m.returnValue());
}
Money Money::operator+(const Money &m)
{
    return Money(value + m.returnValue());
}
Money operator+(std::shared_ptr<Money> money, const Money &m)
{
    return Money(money->returnValue() + m.returnValue());
}

class Bank {
public:
    Bank(Money m) :propertiesBank(std::make_unique<PropertiesBank>(std::move(m))), c(1000) {};
    int returnMoney2() const ;
    int returnMoney1() const { return c.returnValue(); };
    Money addMoney1(const Money &m);
    Money addMoney2(const Money &m);
    ~Bank() = default;
private:
    Money c;
    struct PropertiesBank;
    std::unique_ptr<PropertiesBank> propertiesBank;
};
struct Bank::PropertiesBank
{
    std::shared_ptr<Money> money;
    PropertiesBank(Money&& m) :money(std::make_shared<Money>(m)) {};
};


Money Bank::addMoney1(const Money &m)
{
    c = c + m;
    return c;
}
Money Bank::addMoney2(const Money &m)
{

    return propertiesBank->money + m;
}
int Bank::returnMoney2() const
{
    return propertiesBank->money->returnValue();
}
int main()
{
    Money k(1000);
    Bank bank(k);
    Money h(1000);
    std::cout << bank.returnMoney2() << "\n"; // 1000
    std::cout << k.returnValue() << "\n"; // 1000
    bank.addMoney1(h);
    std::cout << bank.returnMoney1() << "\n"; // 1000, I want 2000
    bank.addMoney2(h);
    std::cout << bank.returnMoney2() << "\n"; // 1000, I want 2000



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Overload operator+ don't work. I have results all operations in "int main()" 1000, but I think that I schould have money = 1000, k = 1000, bank.returnMoney1() = 2000, bank.returnMoney1() = 2000 like in comments

Comment: `Money`'s move assignment operator doesn't assign anything - it's a no-op. The left-hand side of the assignment remains unchanged.

Comment: this is wrong: `Money operator=(Money &&m) { return Money(m.returnValue()); };`   . It should assign to `*this` and return by reference.  You could use `Money &operator=(Money &&m) = default;`